# How to scan a text file and split into 4 arrays equally distributed based on number of lines

Tags: c, arrays

My program scans a text file an returns the number of chars, words , and lines. I need to modify it so that its able to scan a text file into 4 equal parts. The file will contain numbered text files like 
each file name is on a new line.

1_100.txt 
1_101.txt 
1_10.txt 
1_11.txt 
1_12.txt
......

there are about 240 lines of files. Once I have them split into 4 arrays then I need to create 4 threads which will perform the count operations on the files in its array returning 3 values for each file it scanned (words,chars,lines). For now I just need to know how I can split the original text file into 4 arrays, then ill need to figure out how to have each thread match up the value in its array with the actual file so that its counts can be processed.

```
#include "Definition.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ExternalVar.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

extern int Readline(),CountWord(),CountsUpdate();


char Line[MaxLine];  /* array of scanned file */
char Line2[MaxLine]; 
char Line3[MaxLine];
char Line4[MaxLine];

int NChars = 0,  /* number of characters seen so far */
    NWords = 0,  /* number of words seen so far */
    NLines = 0,  /* number of lines seen so far */
    LineLength;  /* length of the current line */ 

int wc = 0,
    lc = 0,
    cc = 0,
    tc = 0;



int i;

main(int argc, char *argv[])  
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen(argv[1],"r");

    if (fp) 
    {
        while(fgets(Line,sizeof Line,fp) != NULL)
        {

        //This is where I need to figure out how to split the array Line into 4 array with equal distribution.
            //create threads and pass each an array
            //threads return counts for their files

        cc = Readline(Line);
        NChars += cc;

        wc = CountWord(Line);
        NWords += wc;

        NLines++;

        }


    printf("Total Lines : %d \n",NLines);
    printf("Total Words : %d \n",NWords);
    printf("Total Chars : %d \n",NChars);
    fclose(fp);
    }
    return 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of splitting them while reading, read them into a single array and sort this array by the size of each file. Then split the big array in round robin manner. This should improve your total processing time. You can do better if you consider the total size and number of files assigned to each thread.

In either case, you can split a list into `N` by using `N` indices each keeping the tail position of a different list:

```
set all indices to 0
for line in file:
     lists[curlist][indices[curlist]++] = line
     curlist = (curlist + 1) % N
```

Comment: hey i tried that it threw off an error saying "

Main.c: In function ‘main’:
Main.c:39:3: error: unknown type name ‘set’
   set all indices to 0
   ^
Main.c:39:11: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘indices’
   set all indices to 0

"

Comment: this is just pseudo code the give you the idea. It cannot possibly compile.

Comment: alright can you help break it down for me I don't fully understand because I am new to C programming, this is literally my second program ever written. I scanned entire file into an Array called "Line". The text file comprises of just a single text file name on every line ex: 1_101.txt \n 1_102.txt\n and so forth. Since I already know the file is 240 lines how do I split say the first 60 elements (0-59) into a new array, and elements(60-119), (120-179), (180-239) each into their own arrays as well.

the pseudo code you posted says lists[curlist][indices[curlist]++] = Line is that a 2d array